# What does "where" mean in a C# class declaration?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I tried to google this, but all I could find was documents on ordinary class declarations.

```
public class DataContextWrapper<T> : IDataContextWrapper where T : DataContext, new()
{

}
```

I see that the class implements IDataContextWrapper, inherits from DataContext and varies with type T depending on how it is instantiated.

I don't know what "`where T`" or the "`, new()`" might mean.

Comment: Consider reading the C# specification when you have a question about language syntax; it is quite detailed.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) and restricts what types can be passed into the generic parameter.

In your case it requires that `T` is indentical to or derived from `DataContext` and has a default(argumentless) constructor(the `new()` constraint).

You need generic constraints to actually do something non trivial with a generic type.

- The `new()` constraint allows you to create an instance with `new T()`.
- The `DataContext` constraint allows you to call the methods of `DataContext` on an instance of `T`

MSDN wrote:

> `where T : <base class name>`
>   The type argument must be or derive from the specified base class.
>
> `where T : new()`
>   The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.

Comment: +1, but where T:class is different from where T:SomeClassName, so the first part of the MSDN snippet isn't relevant to the OP.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - Excellent answer. I'm curious though, why would anyone specify an actual type (e.g., where T : DataContext). The whole point of generics is to specify the type at runtime.

Comment: @Randy Minder - its not more usual with generics to specify the type at *runtime* than regular types. One still usually specifies the type arguments in code. And concrete type constraints are useful whenever the calling code requires a specific base type, be it interfaces, abstract classes or concrete classes.

Comment: @Randy while it doesn't make sense to use a sealed type as constraint, a non sealed class with virtual or abstract methods still makes sense. And one usually doesn't specify the generic parameter at runtime. It is specified when I specialize the generic, which typically happens in a variable declaration/instantiation.

Comment: if we want type argument must have a public constructor with single parameter of string type, then what change do we have to do ?

Comment: @Hot You can't use a generic constraint for that. You're left with reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance`) or some kind of factory delegate. But you won't get compile time checks.

Answer (score 13):

Only allow types T that are derived from or implement DataContext, and have a public constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: `T` must also represent a non-abstract type. This is important because it's legal to call `new T()` when the `new()` constraint has been imposed. Also, if `DataContext` is a class, `T` *can* be `DataContext` itself (rather than derived from it).

Answer (score 9):

It's a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d5x73970.aspx) and specifies constraint on the generic types (for example, only classes, or must implement a specific interface).

In this case, `T` must be a class that is either `DataContext` or inherits from it and must have a parameterless public constructor (the `new()` constraint).

Answer (score 6):

It's a generic type restriction. In this case, T must inherit from DataContext and be a type with a constructor that takes no arguments.

Comment: It need not be a reference type. `new()` applies to structs, as well.

Answer (score 5):

The `where` keyword is used to constrain your generic type variable, in your case it means that the type `T` must be a `DataContext` and must contain a public default constructor.

Comment: That should be "*must* contain a public default constructor"

Answer (score 4):

where T: DataContext reads as: T must be a (or derived from a) DataContext
the ", new()" reads as: must have an parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 2):

It is constraints in the types that can be used as generic. This gives you compiler checks plus the ability to do something meaningful with T.

Ie. `new()` tells the compiler that T has to have a parameterless constructor. This means that you can instantiate instances of T by writing `new T();` and by knowing T is a DataContext as well, you can both make instances of T but also call methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a generics constraint. 
MSDN has more information on that.

See [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Where is there to place a constraint upon the type of T. The new says that the type T must be instantiable without any parameters. ie T thing = new T();

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)